# Text from column cut off- HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

I have 3 columns on a page. They all have text in them but not the same amount. My background color for the columns only covers the columns up until the text and not all the way down to the page. I want the background color to be displayed from where the text starts to the bottom of the page stopping just above my footer. I tried playing around with my padding and margin but I'm having trouble fixing it. I can't insert a picture since I just made my account but to paint a picture for you the columns are side by side but different heights, they are not aligned. Can someone please help me out, here is my code:

Thanks!

```
/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  align-content: center;
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: lightgray;
}


/*Headings in columns*/
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: darkslateblue;
  margin: 10px;
}


/*All text in columns*/
#columntext {
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: justify-all;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: darkslateblue;
}


/*Centers all columns with margin*/
#allcolumns {
  align-content: center;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

Comment: add a row div or a parent div to column and add CSS like 
.row{display:flext;flex-wrap:wrap} and remove float:left from .column class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking - I'd recommend including your HTML if possible?

If you're using an id it should only apply to one item on the page, I assume that #columntext is being used for each instance of column text? In which case make this a class instead, same for #allcolumns.

You mention they each float left and are different heights, are these three separate entire tables with a single column? If you're wanting them all to be the same height just make them inside of a single table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><h2>Lorem ipsum</h2></th>
    <th><h2>Lorem ipsum</h2></th>
    <th><h2>Lorem ipsum</h2></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent 
    </td>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent 
    </td>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you include your HTML it'll be much easier to see what you are trying to do

P.S. I'd recommend using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) above floats if this is an option as floats are being phased out!

Comment: Forgot about flexbox,  I added display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap; and it fixed the problem, thanks @VevG @Deepak!